# Does tardigrade eat mould?

Tags: mycology

There is a problem of devastating [mold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mold) in ventilation of old buildings in Europe. I guess [tardigrades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade) might be better solution because chemicals is not a good idea for ventilation because people are breathing with this air.

Comment: can you add some links to the terms - especially "tardigrade" - in your question? it's kind of hard to follow - it would definitely benefit from some more background information.

Comment: 'mold' is an informal term for various cotton-like-looking fungus of separate taxonomic group. From description I think, that ventilation might build-up of mostly dust and soot ((as seen in cities, characteristically on ceiling fans)), not solely moulds. Is that?

Comment: The wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade) shows tardigrades are aquatic. So why they will stay alive in your ventilators to eat the moulds? Why you thought that... are you telling about any particular sort of tardigrades that is terrestrial and can eat moulds? Do you have any sort of source?

Comment: Majority of more then nine hundred of known species of tardigrades are populates mossy and lichen pillows on the earth, the trees, the cliffs and the rock walls. I seen huge black tardigrades about 1.5mm at wall with mold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mould in buildings can be serious.  It is treated by removing and destroying (fire is good) the things the mould is growing on, and lots of cleaning.

The mould grows on wet cellulosic material like fiber board, gypsum board, paper, or wood.  It can be prevented by fixing the leaks so stuff doesn't get wet, and more cleaning.

You could pour bleach on the contaminated material, kill some of the mould, and what survived would grow back.  Neither chemicals, nor tartigrades are any help here.  Just more cleaning.

Details:  http://www.cdc.gov/mold/stachy.htm